# Algolia indices structure setup

Tags: php, indexing, algolia

I'm brand new to Algolia and I'm a bit confused how to structure my data when I index it.

I have two models in my local database called 'Films' and 'Categories' and they are joined by a pivot table to manage the many to many relationship.

I want users to be able to search by Film title and then have categories as a filter, but I also want users to be able to browse a category.

If I create two indices called Films and Categories, how will these relate? How will algolia know what films belong to which categories?

The documentation doesn't seem clear on this: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/structuring-your-data/

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case what you want is to search a `Film`.
You have to see an index as a non-relational database that allows you to search a unique entity. It's very different than a relational database and does not serve the same purpose.

So you don't need to create two indices, only one index containing Film data (as the name, description...) and the film categories.

You data structure should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "A Movie",
    "categories": [
      "Comedy",
      "Action"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Another Movie",
    "categories": [
      "Horror",
      "Action"
    ]
  }
]
```

Here `name` and `categories` can be searchable attributes.
And `categories` will be a facet, allowing you to filter by category.

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree this does seem best but loading the relationships bloats the record.